# What devices can these various Android OS be placed on?

Tags: jquery, android, html, jquery-mobile

I am developing a jquerymobile app for Android 2,3,4, iPhone,iPad,iPod touch. I'm currently catching some user-agent strings and processing them with jquery and using jquerymobile.

Using the emulator I noticed all 3.X (honeycomb) devices seem to be only tablets, I've had Android 4 and 2 only on small devices.

I need to know:

Can honeycomb devices be small devices?
Can non-honeycomb devices (A2, A4) be tablet devices?

If honeycomb is just for tablets, does that mean say a Samsung galaxy, on Android 2, can NEVER upgrade to Android 3? But bypass it and go straight to 4? Or is 4 only allowed for the most modern Android devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the wiki

```
On 22 February 2011, the Android 3.0 (Honeycomb) SDK – the first
tablet-only Android update – was released, based on Linux kernel
2.6.36. The first device featuring this version, the Motorola Xoom
tablet, was released on 24 February 2011.
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history#v3.x_Honeycomb